# Servo Motor using Netbeans And RXTX

Tags: netbeans, arduino, rxtx, servo

I have an arduino code for my Coinslot and Servo Motor, my question is how can I set the Port Identifiers of Coinslot and Servo Motor, because everytime I inserted a coin my servo motor also moves

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I'd use Javino middleware instead of RxTx.

You'll have to code your coinslot sensor to send to Java the information that a coin was inserted or to program in Java asking how many coins arduino read. For this, Javino provides 2 modes: the listening mode for the first one and the request mode for the second one.

This is it, if I understood correctly.

Comment: do you have any link where can i use Javino?

Comment: is javino applicable in java netbeans?

Comment: Yes, it is. Javino has a library for Java. So, you have to import it into your project. Are you using Arduino with the servo motor?